# Bind a nullable bit field to the TextMode property of a Textbox in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, eval

I have a table with a list of questions. One of the properties is `largeText`.
`NULL` means hide the textbox
`TRUE` means show a MultiLine textbox
`FALSE` means show a single line textbox.

Here's what I am trying to do

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxFreeResponse" runat="server"
             Visible='<%# Eval("largeText") != null %>'
             TextMode = '<%# (Eval("largeText") == (object)true) ?
                               TextBoxMode.SingleLine : 
                               TextBoxMode.MultiLine%>'/>
```

The `Eval("largeText") == (object)true` always evaluates to `FALSE` though. What am I missing? The `(object)` cast is necessary because otherwise it complains about type incompatibility.

Comment: Have you tried casting the `Eval("largeText")` to a boolean and evaluating that in the expression?  Of course, if it's null you'll get an exception, so will need to handle that too.

Comment: I tried `bool` and `bool?`, but I get an exception. I know I can do this in the code-behind, but I feel like I am close to a solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what did the trick for me, hopefully someone will find this useful.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxFreeResponse" runat="server" 
             Visible='<%# Eval("largeText") != null %>'
             TextMode = '<%# (!(Eval("largeText") is DBNull) && (bool)Eval("largeText")) ? 
                             TextBoxMode.MultiLine :
                             TextBoxMode.SingleLine%>'/>
```